# DropDown issue in firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a dropdown for marking messages are read, I have implemented it with ajax call, it is working fine on IE and Chrome but i am having issue in firefox, after reutrning data from my Controller, success function of below code has an argument name result, in IE and
Chrome it is working fine( i am sending its value true) but in case of firefox it is showing error msg(ReferenceError: result is not defined) i have checked this error on console. I am using Jquery's version 1.6

```
 $("#mark").change(function () {
            var message = $('#move_folder').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/Message/TakeActions'
                            + '?message=' + message,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $.toJSON(msgsData),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == true) {
                        // window.location.href = "/inviteFriends/Index";
                        window.location.reload();
                        DivMsgText("Message moved successfully to" + message);                            
                        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
                        for (var i = 0; i < $('.case').length; i++) {
                            if ($('.case')[i].checked)
                                $('.case')[i].checked = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (message == "mark_read") {
                            alert("Select a message to mark as read");
                        }
                        else {
                            // DivMsgText("Select a message to move");
                            alert("Select a message to move");
                        }
                        $("#divmsg").empty();
                        $("#divmsg").removeClass("success grid_9");
                        $("#divmsg").html().remove();
                    }
                },               
                async: false,
                cache: false
            });
        });
```

Comment: Why after calling `window.location.reload();` you continue to write javascript? When you call this function the page reloads.

Comment: I have to reload the page, This code is working fine on IE and chrome

Comment: if you reload the page javascript stops executing. It's a pure chance that your code works in IE and Chrome. Maybe it takes a little more time to reload the page and a couple additional lines can be executed. Anyway, you shouldn't be using any javascript after reloading a page or redirecting to another page. Also why are you manipulating raw DOM elements: `$('.case')[i].checked` instead of using jQuery objects?

Comment: I have removed window.reload() but still having the same issue, result is appearing null in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the following loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.case').length; i++) {
    if ($('.case')[i].checked)
        $('.case')[i].checked = false;
}
```

with this:

```
$('.case').removeAttr('checked');
```

Also make sure you properly URL encode your query string parameters:

```
'?message=' + encodeURIComponent(message)
```

Also you shouldn't be using any javascript after `window.location.reload();`. This function does what it name suggests: it reloads the page by navigating away from it which as a consequence might stop the execution of any subsequent js.

Also try to return a valid JSON object from your `TakeActions` controller action:

```
public ActionResult TakeActions()
{
    ...
    return Json(new { status = true });
}
```

and then on the client side use the following test:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result.status) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem with your code is that I suspect you only returned true:

```
public ActionResult TakeActions()
{
    ...
    return Json(true);
}
```

which sends the string `true` into the response which is an invalid JSON string and yet you are telling jQuery that your server returns JSON by setting `dataType: 'json'`.

And yet another remark: you seem to be using some `message` variable which is not declared anywhere in the scope you have shown in your question. Is this variable actually declarzed somewhere? Is it declared in a scope which is accessible within your function?

Comment: I am returning  return Json(true); in my Controller

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi, this might be the problem. Try returning `Json(new { status = true });` and then on the client test `if (result.status) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

the code after window.location.reload(); will not be executed. The reasons that's working in some browsers is that your window.location.reload(); is not working there, you should use window.location.reload(true); but at the end of succes-function and maybe with a little timeout before...